# I want to install matplotlib on pypy in windows but I cannot

Tags: matplotlib, pypy

I want to install matplotlib on pypy in windows but I cannot

here is my errors:

```
Building wheel for pillow (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\pypy3.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\mypc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-aldxfgwi\\pillow_36442a23e4bc45babfe05dc3de237b82\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\mypc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-aldxfgwi\\pillow_36442a23e4bc45babfe05dc3de237b82\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-sghjaqiu'
```

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> 'C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\pypy3.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys,
> setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-aldxfgwi\
> pillow_36442a23e4bc45babfe05dc3de237b82\setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Temp\  pip-install-aldxfgwi\pillow_36442a23e4bc45babfe05dc3de237b82\setup.py'"'"';f
> = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)  (**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import
> setup; setup()'"'"');code =   f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install  --record
> 'C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-185nr5jz\install-record.txt'
> --single-version-externally-managed  --compile --install-headers 'C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\include\pillow' Check the logs for full
> command output.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem when installing matplotlib on PYPY. The reason is that some dependencies of matplotlib haven't been installed in PYPY. My solution is to install numpy before matplotlib. It works for me. Here shows the commands:

`pip_pypy install numpy`

`pip_pypy install matplotlib`